# Enough to stack overflow?

Tags: java

Java.

Is it normal that i get stack overflow error after 10 000 recursive void function calls with a reference and two integers as arguments?

Got 6gb ram memory, tried running through IDE and command line. I'm pretty sure the code is correct and recursion should finish.

It's about a Fill tool for a tile map editor. It start's at a certain tile and goes up, down, right and left if the coincident tile is of the same type and doesn't come back.

Tried different approaches, here is the one with additional boolean table indicating whether [x][y] tile was visited and replacing marked tiles after recursion is done:

```
public void fillRec(Tile t, int column, int row) {
    if (affected[column][row] || t.getName() != pattern)
        return;

    /*t.replaceMe(editor.currentTileButton.spawnTile(column, row, 
            editor.tileMap));*/
    affected[column][row] = true;

    if (column < editor.tileMap.tilesX - 1) {
        fillRec(editor.tileMap.tiles[column + 1][row], column + 1, row);
    }
    if (column > 0) {
        fillRec(editor.tileMap.tiles[column - 1][row], column - 1, row);
    }
    if (row < editor.tileMap.tilesY - 1) {
        fillRec(editor.tileMap.tiles[column][row + 1], column, row + 1);
    }
    if (row > 0) {
        fillRec(editor.tileMap.tiles[column][row - 1], column, row - 1);
    }
}
```

This works fine with ~75x75 map, so did functions replacing tile and doing other heavy stuff in their bodies.

Comment: `"I'm pretty sure the code is correct and recursion should finish."` -- but without pertinent code, we can't be sure of anything. If I were in your shoes, I also wouldn't make any assumptions about correctness if my code were not behaving as expected. Please consider posting a decent [mcve] for us to test and review.

Comment: What is the objective of your program ?

Comment: Post your code. In general, recursion requires adequate `stack` size.

Comment: In case of doubt you could increase the stack size in the VM arguments.

Comment: It seems like 1MB of memory allows roughly 10 000 levels of recursion of the function like yours; OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14). For 200MB it got to ~2760k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much data these functions place on the stack in relation to the configured (or default) stack size, so it's not only the stack size used by the arguments to the function call.

So yes, it does not sound unnormal. You should play with the stack size or implement it differently.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, each method call uses up a Stack frame. If you want to use large scale recursion in Java, you'll need to use a Trampoline - which can swap stack space for heap space. A trampoline typically has two states

1. completed
2. more work to do

The completed state holds the final result, and the more work to do can be implemented with a Supplier (in Java 8) or similar construct, that makes the next recursive call. The Trampoline implementation should manages the calls to your method, and iterates rather than recurses.

Here is a simple looping example with a Trampoline.

```
 Trampoline<Integer> loop(int times,int sum){

    if(times==0)
        return Trampoline.done(sum);
    else
        return Trampoline.more(()->loop(times-1,sum+times));
 }
```

To make the call to loop

```
 loop(100,10).result();
```

Note the method returns a lazy Trampoline Object immediately (i.e. it doesn't perform the summing), and the Trampoline runs through the simple summing algorithm when result is called - in an iterative, rather than recursive fashion.

There is a Trampoline implementation in a library I wrote called [cyclops-trampoline](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/tree/master/cyclops-functions) that you can use. Or if you prefer here is how to roll your own (this implementation makes use of a nice technique by Mario Fusco of managing the trampoline iteration in a Java 8 Stream).

```
 public interface Trampoline<T> {


default Trampoline<T> bounce(){
    return this;
}


T result();


default boolean complete() {
    return true;
}



public static <T> Trampoline<T> done(T result) {
    return () -> result;
}


public static <T> Trampoline<T> more(Trampoline<Trampoline<T>> trampoline) {
    return new Trampoline<T>() {

        @Override
        public boolean complete() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Trampoline<T> bounce() {
            return trampoline.result();
        }

        public T result() {
            return trampoline(this);
        }

        T trampoline(Trampoline<T> trampoline) {

            return Stream.iterate(trampoline,Trampoline::bounce)
                        .filter(Trampoline::complete)
                        .findFirst()
                        .get()
                        .result();


         }
      };
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds normal.  If you don't specify otherwise, the default Java stack size is 1Mb or less, depending on your JVM and execution platform.  A stack overflow at ~10,000 recursive calls sounds quite plausible for a stack with the default size.

- You can change the JVM's default stack size with the `-Xss` option; e.g. `-Xss10m` sets the default size to 10MB.
- You can also specify a thread stack size directly via the `Thread` constructor.

---

However, this does illustrate a point that is not obvious to new Java programmers.  Unlike typical functional programming languages (and many others) the standard Java implementations do not do "tail call optimization".  This means that a recursive call sequence always needs stack space that is proportional to the maximum recursion depth.

This is a potential problem for programmers who prefer to use recursion rather than iteration.  Unfortunately, if your data is such that deep recursion is a possibility, you really need to convert to an iterative solution.  (Or find some other way to move the "recursion state" off the stack.)